# How to convert FASTA files into DNAbin?

Tags: r, fasta

I have a fasta file of 30 sequences, and I want to use the `BarcodingR` package in R. However, the package requires that the data be in a DNAbin format.

How can I convert Fasta input into DNAbin?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `adegenet` R package to convert FASTA into DNAbin.
See [this function](https://rdrr.io/cran/adegenet/man/fasta2DNAbin.html) for example.

For further help, it could be better for you to provide some code you tested or that we can use to reproduce your issue.